# Why does getting my form with document.getElementByID stop alert() from firing?

Tags: javascript, dom, alert

I'm trying to alert the values of the form elements but this isn't functioning even at its simplest: getting the elements of the form then alerting a string.

The alert fires when it's by itself, but not when I put the form's data in the variable. Why?

I'm sure there's probably a very simple mistake in here somewhere, but I'm stumped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- ISTE240 Exercise 5b -->
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Get elements from a form</title>

<script>
function getFormValues() {
// function to send first and last names to an 'alert' message.
   alert("test");
   var form = document.getElementById(“regForm”).elements;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>JavaScript Exercise 5b </p> 
<form id="regForm" onsubmit="getFormValues()">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Boo"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Radley"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors.

Comment: You're using "curly" quotes rather than ASCII double quotes, so the code doesn't parse and nothing runs.

Comment: what does the debugger say in the browser console when you try it? It is not working because it is error out somewhere. Hit F12 and look at console.

Comment: I just realized the curly quotes were causing this - thanks! If you can post that as an answer, Barmar, I'll accept as soon as I can.

Comment: For the record the culprit seems to be google docs - I was writing in it originally and it apparently replaced the normal quotes.

Comment: Also, it may have to do with it not being a string, even though it would seem to display the object serialized. Try it with (elements.length) and see if that works. If so, that is the issue.

Comment: Not exactly related, but even the fixed code would probably not do what you expect. The form is submitted, and a server will load a new page as a response.

Comment: I don't think Google Docs is meant to be used as a code editor.

Comment: It's definitely not optimal - I just forgot my USB stick today and stuck my code in a doc so I could access it again when I got home. Learned my lesson about that! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `form` tag will try to submit form values. You must prevent default behavior, demo below

```js
document.querySelector('#regForm').onsubmit = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('a');
  
  var form = document.getElementById("regForm").elements; //<-- wrong syntax, must be "
  console.log(form);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- ISTE240 Exercise 5b -->
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Get elements from a form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>JavaScript Exercise 5b</p>
  <form id="regForm">
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="Boo">
    <br>Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="Radley">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a very good point in addition to the quotes; thank you!